# Let A, B and U be sets so that A ⊆ U and B ⊆ U. Prove A = ∅ iff the equality ((U∖A) ∩ B) ∪ (A ∩ (U∖B)) = B holds.

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Ive done the prove for =>, and would need help in proving <=
I tried proving <= by contradiction, but I am stuck now.

My <= procedure is as follow

Suppose ((U∖A) ∩ B) ∪ (A ∩ (U∖B)) = B
Proving by contradiction, let A = ∅, this means that there exists x, such that x ∈ A.

Assuming that x ∉ B, then A ∩ (U∖B) = A, which also means ((U∖A) ∩ B) ∪ (A ∩ (U∖B)) ≠ B. Since this contradicts assumption, it can be concluded that A ⊆ B.

Is my current procedure correct, if yeas, how do i continue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Suppose $\;x\in A\;$ , then

$$\begin{align*}&\color{Red}{x\in B}:\;\implies x\notin A\cap(U\setminus B)\,,\,\,\text{so it must be that}\;\;x\in (U\setminus A)\cap B\implies\\&x\notin A\,,\;\;\text{contradiction}\\{}\\
&\color{red}{x\notin B}:\;\implies x\in A\cap(U\setminus B)\subset B\implies x\in B\,,\,\,\text{contradiction, again}\end{align*}$$